# While echo - dont write mutiple lines, overwrite one instead

Tags: php, html

im trying to write a loop that displays the counter on one line, been sitting here for over an hour but cant figure it out.

The main loop is

```
while($counter< 100){               
    echo $counter;
    usleep($timeInSeconds*1000000);
    $counter=$counter+1;
}
```

Now this prints 100 numbers after a delay each on a new line. Is it possible for the echo to instead replace itself for each loop?

---

I tried many options, here is one that didnt crash:

```
while($counter < 100){

        $counter=$counter+1;
        echo $counter;
        usleep($timeInSeconds*1000000);

        flush();
        ob_flush();    
    }
```

However, with this option it works in one line with a delay, but it doesnt clear the previous echo, so its just a bunch of number next to each other

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do something on the server that should be done on the client.

I expect you are making a timer. You should write some JavaScript code instructing the web browser on how to display multiple numbers with a delay in between. Your current code will show a loading wheel and a blank screen for the entire duration on many browsers.

Instead, replace your loop with something like:

```js
var time_in_seconds = 1; // You can replace 1 with the value of the PHP variable
var count_element = document.getElementById("example_counter");
var n = 0;
var interval_id;

function update_counter(){
  n += 1;
  if (n >= 100) {
    clearInterval(interval_id);
  }
  count_element.textContent = n;
}

interval_id = setInterval(update_counter, time_in_seconds * 1000);
```

```html
<span id="example_counter"></span>
```

Comment: Okay, I have tried with javascript aswell, it works better, but it still displays multiple outputs in one line while im trying to rewrite the output on each loop

Comment: @D.re48 Don't have a PHP loop. Instead, write an HTML / JavaScript instruction to display a timer. If you have delays in your PHP code, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: @D.re48 If this solved your problem, please click the grey tick underneath the voting buttons on the answer to mark it as accepted.